# React router v4, redux and immutable integration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have migrated my code to use React (15.5.4), React Router v4 (4.1.1), Redux (3.6.0), Immutable (3.8.1) and am now having a difficult time understanding this rigmarole.

I used Redux-auth ( https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/redux-auth ) as a base for the authentication for my app. It was working fine till I wanted to migrate the react-router library. As far as I understand, auth variable is not getting passed to the component. After reading a couple of blog articles, it seems like withRouter seems the go. I'm not sure how to use it though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am getting this error:
[image]

I use Lynn's code for OAuthSignInButton except change how it is exported because from my understanding, now connect will not work with the latest migrations:

```
import { oAuthSignIn as _oAuthSignIn } from '../../actions/users/oauth-sign-in';

// hook for rewire
var oAuthSignIn = _oAuthSignIn;

class OAuthSignInButton extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    provider: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    label: PropTypes.string,
    signInParams: PropTypes.object,
    children: PropTypes.node,
    icon: PropTypes.node
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    signInParams: {},
    children: <span>OAuth Sign In</span>,
    icon: <span></span>
  };

  getEndpoint() {
    return (
      this.props.endpoint ||
      this.props.auth.getIn(['configure', 'currentEndpointKey']) ||
      this.props.auth.getIn(['configure', 'defaultEndpointKey'])
    );
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.props.dispatch(oAuthSignIn({
      provider: this.props.provider,
      params: this.props.signInParams,
      endpointKey: this.getEndpoint()
    }))
      .then(this.props.next)
      .catch(() => {});
  }

  render() {
    let disabled = this.props.auth.getIn(['user', 'isSignedIn']);
    let loading = (
      (this.props.auth.getIn(['ui', 'oAuthSignInLoadingProvider']) === this.props.provider) &&
      this.props.auth.getIn(['oAuthSignIn', this.getEndpoint(), 'loading'])
    );

    return (
      <ButtonLoader
        loading={loading}
        className={`${this.props.className} oauth-sign-in-submit`}
        disabled={disabled}
        onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
        {...this.props}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default OAuthSignInButton;
```

Here is the main container:

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    dispatch: PropTypes.func,
    pageEndpoint: PropTypes.string,
    theme: PropTypes.string,
    currentUserUid: PropTypes.string,
    currentUserProvider: PropTypes.string,
    currentUserEndpoint: PropTypes.string,
  };

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Theme.OAuthSignInButton
               provider="facebook"
               endpoint={this.props.pageEndpoint}
               default
               bsStyle="default"
               style={{ padding: 0, borderStyle: 'none' }}
             >
              <img src={require('../assets/btn_facebook1.png')} />
             </Theme.OAuthSignInButton>     
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Redux auth reducer look like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';

/* reducers */
export const authStateReducer = combineReducers({
  configure,
  oAuthSignIn,
  ui,
  user
});
```

Sample of one of my reducers:

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
  loading: true,
  errors: null,
  config: null,
  endpointKeys: null,
  defaultEndpointKey: null,
  currentEndpointKey: null
});

export default function configureReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STORE_CURRENT_ENDPOINT_KEY:
      return ({ currentEndpointKey }) => state.merge({ currentEndpointKey });
    case SET_ENDPOINT_KEYS:
      return ({ endpointKeys, defaultEndpointKey, currentEndpointKey }) => state.merge({
        endpointKeys, defaultEndpointKey, currentEndpointKey
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Main reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { authStateReducer } from './users';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';


export default (combineReducers({
  auth: authStateReducer,
  router: routerReducer
}));
```

Redux store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';

import reducer from '../reducers';

const middleware = routerMiddleware(history);

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(middleware));

export default store;
```

My client.js file looks like this:

```
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { Route } from 'react-router';

import Main from './containers/Main';
import store from './store';

const history = createHistory();

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Component} />
          </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </Provider>
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById('content')
  );
};

render(Main);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./containers/Main', render);
}
```

Comment: You have to `connect` `OAuthSignInButton` to allow it to dispatch and use the state...

Comment: export default connect(({ auth }) => ({ auth }))(OAuthSignInButton); and export default connect(({ auth }) => ({ auth }))(Main); gives the same error